# Where is the X509 defined (typedef, define, whatever...) in openssl?

Tags: c, openssl, x509certificate

I am newbie in this area... That said, any basic programming in openssl has to deal with X509 certificates and definitions of the type:

```
     X509 *certificate
```

I tried to grep for X509 in openssl includes at /usr/include/openssl/*.h but could not find the definition of X509 though there are plenty of usage of the same. There are too many files to manually go through. Can you point me to the include file and the definition/declaration/macro or whatever of X509? Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place.

Comment: `typedef struct x509_st X509;` in [include/openssl/types.h](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/types.h#L144)

Comment: @kaylum Your comment enabled me to locate the typedef in /usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h   but I am unable to locate the declaration of the struct x509_st. I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You can find the description into [include/crypto/x509.h](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/33388b44b67145af2181b1e9528c381c8ea0d1b6/include/crypto/x509.h#L161)

```
struct x509_st {
    X509_CINF cert_info;
    X509_ALGOR sig_alg;
    ASN1_BIT_STRING signature;
    X509_SIG_INFO siginf;
    CRYPTO_REF_COUNT references;
    CRYPTO_EX_DATA ex_data;
    /* These contain copies of various extension values */
    long ex_pathlen;
    long ex_pcpathlen;
    uint32_t ex_flags;
    uint32_t ex_kusage;
    uint32_t ex_xkusage;
    uint32_t ex_nscert;
    ASN1_OCTET_STRING *skid;
    AUTHORITY_KEYID *akid;
    X509_POLICY_CACHE *policy_cache;
    STACK_OF(DIST_POINT) *crldp;
    STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME) *altname;
    NAME_CONSTRAINTS *nc;
# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
    STACK_OF(IPAddressFamily) *rfc3779_addr;
    struct ASIdentifiers_st *rfc3779_asid;
# endif
    unsigned char sha1_hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    X509_CERT_AUX *aux;
    CRYPTO_RWLOCK *lock;
    volatile int ex_cached;

    /* Set on live certificates for authentication purposes */
    ASN1_OCTET_STRING *distinguishing_id;
} /* X509 */ ;
```

Comment: I found it in /usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:  typedef struct x509_st X509  But I am unable to find the declaration of the struct in any of the /usr/include/openssl/*.h files. I am on Ubuntu 8.04.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 18.04 not 8.04... sorry about the typo.

Comment: This is the principe of isolation, you should not handle x509_st by hand if you just want to interact with the lib, you should use the exposed API. If you want to do some dev inside openssl, you can do it using the source code.

Comment: I wasn't planning to handle it by hand (presuming that you meant using the elements directly). I just wanted to know the structure or even know that it was indeed a struct. Certainly helps in debugging and removing compiler warnings.